# Bootstrap carousel issue with bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on bootstrap popover using popover api and then using ajax call setting the contents of the popover. Contents include a bootstrap carousel with few items in it.

The prob is that when i click on carousel 'prev' and 'next' buttons, they don't work and instead browser url changes to www.test.com#carouselid and popover closes as data-trigget is set to 'focus'.

I need to close the popover only when i click outside the popover and while i click on carousel buttons then carousel should work and popover should not close.

Here is the code:

```js
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.callAPIController = function () {        
        var dataElement = this.options.contentWrapperId;
        var $tip = this.tip();
        var id = '45678';        
        var requestObject = {                           
                id: id 
        };         
        var currentElement = this.$element;
        $(this).popover('fullwidth');       
            this.tip().spin({
                'background-color': "white",
                'color': "black",
                'length': 3
            });
            my.Ajax.post("/api/getitems", requestObject)
                .done(function (result) {                   
                    
                    $(currentElement).popover('fullwidth');                   
                    //var inHtml = "<div class='arrow' style = 'display: none;'></div><h3 class='popover-title' style = 'display: none;'></h3><div class='popover-content'>" + result.viewData.data.response + "</div>";
                    var inHtml = result.viewData.data.response;
                    $tip.html(inHtml);                    
                    $(currentElement).popover('show');
                    $(currentElement).popover('reposition');
                    $(currentElement).popover('fullwidth');
                })
                .fail(function (result) {                    
                    alert('');
                });            
       
    };
```

```css
.popover {
    max-width: 700px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.popover-title {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.bundle-individual-product {
    max-width: 400px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.bundle-first-product {
    border-right: solid 1px #ddd;
}

.bundle-last-product {
    border-left: solid 1px #ddd;
}

.bundle-product-image {
    /* max-width: 100px; */
    margin: auto;
}

.flexy {
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-arrow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bundle-item {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-control, .carousel-control:visited {
    color: #2375b7;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    color: #2375b7;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide all the dependencies for your code snippet?

Comment: @beerwin  - Jquery version being used is 1.12.4 and bootstrap is 3.3.5